# Displaying Images from a folder in PHP

Tags: php, image, directory

I am currently creating an e-commerce website where I retrieve the vehicle details from the database and search for its image in a folder. I used the code below for searching the folder for the image, but it only show the name of the JPG file and not the image of it. Could anyone help to to determine how I could display the image of the vehicle

```
$imageName=$_POST['car'];
if ($handle = opendir('Images/$imageName')) {
   $dir_array = array();
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
$dir_array[] = $file;
}
}    
echo $dir_array[rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)];
 closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: you have to use normal HTML for this. eg. `echo '<img src="'.$dir_array[rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)].'" />';`

Comment: hi what im $imageName? Is the the image that you want to display? Is it unique for every image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put html tags around the result. Try:

`echo "<img src='PATH_TO_IMAGE/".$dir_array[rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)]."'>";`

where PATH_TO_IMAGE is the relative/absolute url address to your images folder

Ex

`echo "<img src='/images/".$dir_array[rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)]."'>";`

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the path to the image inside an img HTML tag, otherwise it is just plain text.

```
echo '<img src="Images/' . $imageName . $dir_array[rand(0,count($dir_array)-1)] . '" alt="" />';
```

I hope you're doing some validation/sanitisation on $_POST['car'] somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If you have the name of the JPG, use `<img src="NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE.JPG" />` ...